# Why Promise returns also Resolve on Reject

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

can someone explain, why Promise fires then() function (and also catch() function) when reject is called?

When resolve is called, only then() is trigger - OK

When reject is called, both then() and catch() function are called - Problem

```
static logIn(email, password) {

    async function getSession () {

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('email', email);
        data.append('password', password);

        const response = await fetch(
            url,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                mode:   'cors',
                body:   data,
                cache:  'no-cache',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                },
            }
        );

        const json = await response.json();

        return json;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getSession()
            .then(json => {
                if (json.status === 'ok') {
                    resolve('OK');
                } else {
                    reject('LogIn failed.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => reject('LogIn failed.'))

    });

};

logIn()
    .then(console.log('logged in'))
    .catch(error => console.log('not logged in'));
```

Comment: What gets logged?

Comment: You have multiple `then`s, which is the one you believe is being incorrectly called in case of rejection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice this line:

```
.then(console.log('logged in'))
```

`then` method expects a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), but you're invoking a function and passing the `return` value as parameter. If console.log returned a function, that function would be invoked internally by `then` in case the promise was resolved. But this is not the case, since console.log hasn't a return value! (It just prints and exit).

In javascript, no return value is equal to `undefined`. So, what you are doing is **invoking console.log in any case** and passing undefined as parameter. You code is thus equivalent to:

```
console.log('logged in');
...
  .then(undefined)
  ...
```

Probably, what you meant is to pass a logging callback as parameter, and let the *Promise* invoke that callback when it is resolved:

```
.then(() => console.log('logged in'));
```

Or, to be more clean about what's happening, you can see it in this way:

```
function log() {
  console.log('logged in');
}

...
  .then(log);
```

We are not invoking the function, just passing the reference!

Comment: Thanks @Cristian Traina for correct answer! and for explanation.
It really should be callback function (() => console.log('logged in')).

Answer (score 2):

Promises **continue after a catch**, although you're trying to wrap a promise in a promise, so you can manually change the behaviour, that is an anti-pattern. Chaining the promise itself would be better, so you are able to handle errors in the promise chain, and then continue execution (so a catch in the middle can still be followed by a then).

There is no need for `.catch(error => reject('LogIn failed.'))`
 because your catch statement at the bottom will catch the error if you just return the promise from `getSession()`. You are trying to create your own Promise, but as there is already a promise being returned from `getSession()` so what you really want to do is return the promise from that directly.

Finally, you are writing a `console.log` at the bottom without wrapping it in a callback function, so it is firing synchronously, when the promise is invoked, not when `.then` is firing.

A neater solution is:

....

```
    // return the promise from getSession, why wrap it in another?
    return getSession()
        .then(json => {
            if (json.status === 'ok') {
                return 'OK';
            } else {
                // Throwing an error in a then callback will trigger the catch block below
                throw new Error('LogIn failed.');
            }
        });
}

logIn()
    .then(() => console.log('logged in'))
    .catch(error => console.log('not logged in'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Calls onFulfilled or onRejected with the fulfillment value or rejection reason of the promise (as appropriate) and returns a new promise resolving to the return value of the called handler.